# Can't get for loop to work while parsing HTML using Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm using the Beautiful Soup documentation to help me understand how to implement it. I'm not too familiar with Python as a whole, so maybe I'm making a syntax error, but I don't believe so. The code below should print out any links from the main Etsy page, but it's not doing that. The documentation states something similar to this, but maybe I'm missing something. Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# import library
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os.path
from os import path

# Request to website and download HTML contents
url='https://www.etsy.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=etsy_e&utm_campaign=Search_US_Brand_GGL_ENG_General-Brand_Core_All_Exact&utm_ag=A1&utm_custom1=_k_Cj0KCQiAi8KfBhCuARIsADp-A54MzODz8nRIxO2LnGcB8Ezc3_q40IQk9HygcSzz9fPmPWnrITz8InQaAt5oEALw_wcB_k_&utm_content=go_227553629_16342445429_536666953103_kwd-1818581752_c_&utm_custom2=227553629&gclid=Cj0KCQiAi8KfBhCuARIsADp-A54MzODz8nRIxO2LnGcB8Ezc3_q40IQk9HygcSzz9fPmPWnrITz8InQaAt5oEALw_wcB'
req=requests.get(url)
content=req.text

soup=BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

for x in soup.head.find_all('a'):
    print(x.get('href'))
```

The HTML prints if I set it up that way, but I can't get the for loop to work.

Comment: What is the output from your current program?

Comment: @PeterF It won't produce any output

Comment: Main issue here is that you try to select them from the `<head>` but there are no `<a>` so  use `for x in soup.body.find_all('a'):` or `for x in soup.find_all('a'):` instead.

Comment: If there was a syntax error (which there isn't) then you would see a SyntaxError exception when you try to run your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get all  tags from the specified URL then:

```
url = 'https://www.etsy.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=etsy_e&utm_campaign=Search_US_Brand_GGL_ENG_General-Brand_Core_All_Exact&utm_ag=A1&utm_custom1=_k_Cj0KCQiAi8KfBhCuARIsADp-A54MzODz8nRIxO2LnGcB8Ezc3_q40IQk9HygcSzz9fPmPWnrITz8InQaAt5oEALw_wcB_k_&utm_content=go_227553629_16342445429_536666953103_kwd-1818581752_c_&utm_custom2=227553629&gclid=Cj0KCQiAi8KfBhCuARIsADp-A54MzODz8nRIxO2LnGcB8Ezc3_q40IQk9HygcSzz9fPmPWnrITz8InQaAt5oEALw_wcB'

with requests.get(url) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    if (body := soup.body):
        for a in body.find_all('a', href=True):
            print(a['href'])
```